# How to wait for firebase image upload

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, react-native

I am trying to upload multiple images to firebase, but I need the url that is returned before I can continue. Is there any way to wait for that return before continuing?

The code that I have is:

```
data.forEach((element) => {
  const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
  Blob.build(RNFetchBlob.wrap(element.path), { type : 'image/jpeg' })
  .then((blob) => {firebase.storage()
    .ref('images')
    .child(`${sessionId}`)
    .put(blob, { contentType : 'image/png' })
    .then((snapshot) => {
      element.image = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
    })
  });
});

Parse.Cloud.run('doSomething', {
  data : data,
}).then(res => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'WE_DID_SOMETHING',
  });
});
```

I want to have more than one image upload, so I will have multiple calls to firebase before I call Parse. How can I ensure that I have the urls back from the firebase calls before continuing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `Promise.all()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

`Promise.all(array)` will resolve only after all the promises in `array` have resolved.  Have your forEach create a promise object on each iteration (rather than using `.then()` to handle each resolve individually) and push it to an array, then run `Promise.all(array)` after the `data.forEach()` call.